# JavaScript: Can ECMAScript 5's Strict Mode ("use strict") be enabled using single quotes ('use strict')?

Tags: javascript, ecma262, strict, ecmascript-5

JavaScript doesn't care if your Strings are double-quoted `"double"` or single-quoted `'single'`.

Every example of ECMAScript 5's strict mode has it enabled by `"use strict"` in double-quotes. Can I do the following (single-quotes):

```
alert(function(){
  'use strict';
  return !this;
}());
```

This will return *true* if Strict mode is enabled, and *false* if it is not.

Comment: @Myles Gray - I don't have a browser that supports Strict mode at work :(

Comment: @Felix Kling - None of the major browsers support Strict mode :( See http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[For you, without using a browser that supports strict mode](https://web.archive.org/web/20171004053453/http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_14.1):

> A Use Strict Directive is an `ExpressionStatement` in a Directive Prologue whose *`StringLiteral`* is either the exact character sequences `"use strict"` or `'use strict'`. A Use Strict Directive may not contain an EscapeSequence or LineContinuation.

Comment: If you are using gzip to compress the content then I would recommend using double quotes or single quotes depending on which one shows up most in the document.

Comment: Okay, but how about JS engine support? I don't think there are any known quirks at the moment, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: You mean if there is a problem if strict mode is not supported? I highly doubt it. The syntax was chosen to make it backwards compatible. An engine that does not support strict mode simply sees an expression statement with a lone string literal.

Comment: @FelixKling That's not what I meant. I was wondering whether there might be an engine that triggers strict mode when seeing `"use strict"`, but not when seeing `'use strict'`, even though the two are supposed to be equivalent.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Ah. I don't know, I don't think so.

Answer (score 28):

http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_14.1

> A Use Strict Directive is an ExpressionStatement in a Directive Prologue whose StringLiteral is either the exact character sequences **"use strict"** or **'use strict'**. A Use Strict Directive may not contain an EscapeSequence or LineContinuation.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode) you can use both `"use strict";` and `'use strict';`.